# MLflow: Unable to store artifacts to S3

Tags: docker, amazon-s3, boto3, mlflow

I'm running my mlflow tracking server in a docker container on a remote server and trying to log mlflow runs from local computer with the eventual goal that anyone on my team can send their run data to the same tracking server.  I've set the tracking URI to be `http://<ip of remote server >:<port on docker container>`.  I'm not explicitly setting any of the AWS credentials on the local machine because I would like to just be able to train locally and log to the remote server (run data to RDS and artifacts to S3).  I have no problem logging my runs to an RDS database but I keep getting the following error when it get to the point of trying to log artifacts: `botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials`.  Do I have to have the credentials available outside of the tracking server for this to work (ie: on my local machine where the mlflow runs are taking place)?  I know that all of my credentials are available in the docker container that is hosting the tracking server. I've be able to upload files to my S3 bucket using the aws cli inside of the container that hosts my tracking server so I know that it as access.  I'm confused by the fact that I can log to RDS but not S3. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong at this point.  TIA.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, apparently I do need to have the credentials available to the local client as well.

Comment: Not necessarily. It is also possible the make the mlflow server [proxy the artifact store access](https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/tracking.html#scenario-5-mlflow-tracking-server-enabled-with-proxied-artifact-storage-access)

Comment: Thanks bk_ that worked for logging to S3.  Unfortunately, I cannot view the artifacts in the mlflow UI.  Do you know why this might be?